# How to use copyleaks Sandbox for Java SDK?

Tags: java, sdk, integration, sandbox

I downloaded java code from git repo that copyleaks gave, i wanted to try and test out the code.Trying to integrate copyleaks into our application.
I see in code that there is a snadbox that is given and i am wondering how do i use it?

Comment: what did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.